# Way to extend a Path by some unit on Canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have a simple `Path` which i have drawn as

```
animPath.moveTo(360, 360);
animPath.lineTo(500, 200);
```

Now i want to extend this path by lets say 5 units from the last co-ordinate drawn( Because i just want its length to be increased by 5 units and i don't have further x and y co-ordinates). Is there any Android API or simple way to do that? I feel there must be a way like `add(5)` which should extend this path by 5 units in the same direction based on the last co-ordinates. But not able to find any.

Comment: what 5 units? what do you mean?

Comment: @pskink, offset is for moving the complete path altogether from one position to another. I only want to increase its length.

Comment: i thought this is what you wanted, if you want to "extend" your last line segment then no, there is no such way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way to find a third point on a line( with center and an other point known) at a given distance is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27223108/3292108) and it worked for me.

```
Len = Sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1))
Normalized (unit-length) direction vector is

dx = (x2-x1) / Len
dy = (y2-y1) / Len
P3 coordinates for case when P1P3 and P1P2 vectors have the same direction:

x3 = x1 + Distance * dx
y3 = y1 + Distance * dy
for opposite direction:

x3 = x1 - Distance * dx
y3 = y1 - Distance * dy
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there are no API method for this. You can implement it by saving two latest points and (after some mathematic calculations) drawing this offset by adding one more `animPath.lineTo(x, y)` call.